# npm install bcrypt@5 failed

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install bcrypt and it's failing and I don't know why

I'm using npm@8.1.1
and node@v14.17.3

I looked around and couldn't find a solution

this is the error message

> npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! path C:\user\project\node_modules\bcrypt npm
> ERR! command failed npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s
> /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build npm ERR! Failed to execute
> 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
> C:\Users\Isaac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
> configure --fallback-to-build
> --module=C:\user\project\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node
> --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\user\project\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1) npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.6
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@14.17.3 | win32 | x64 npm ERR!
> node-pre-gyp info check checked for
> "C:\user\project\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node"
> (not found) npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET
> https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v5.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install request to
> https://github-releases.githubusercontent.com/611333/2dce3380-7741-11eb-8e53-10fe9e70e497?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20211108%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211108T172227Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=9761816bbd1377deb50f2fa1632743d75dec9aef4f24ef775a4605edddd3dd81&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=611333&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dbcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
> failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate npm ERR!
> node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@5.0.1
> and node@14.17.3 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source
> compile with node-gyp) npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error request to
> https://github-releases.githubusercontent.com/611333/2dce3380-7741-11eb-8e53-10fe9e70e497?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20211108%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211108T172227Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=9761816bbd1377deb50f2fa1632743d75dec9aef4f24ef775a4605edddd3dd81&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=611333&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dbcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
> failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate npm ERR! gyp
> info it worked if it ends with ok npm ERR! gyp info using
> node-gyp@8.3.0 npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.17.3 | win32 | x64 npm
> ERR! gyp info ok npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok npm
> ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0 npm ERR! gyp info using
> node@14.17.3 | win32 | x64 npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python
> version 3.9.4 found at
> "C:\Users\Isaac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" npm
> ERR! gyp http GET
> https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.17.3/node-v14.17.3-headers.tar.gz
> npm ERR! gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install npm ERR!
> gyp ERR! configure error npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack FetchError: request
> to
> https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.17.3/node-v14.17.3-headers.tar.gz
> failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate npm ERR! gyp
> ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.
> (C:\Users\Isaac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:110:14)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:375:28)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener
> (_http_client.js:475:9) npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit
> (events.js:387:35) npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorNT
> (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8) npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at
> emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3) npm ERR! gyp ERR!
> stack     at processTicksAndRejections
> (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) npm ERR! gyp ERR! System
> Windows_NT 10.0.18363 npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node.exe"
> "C:\Users\Isaac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
> "configure" "--fallback-to-build"
> "--module=C:\user\project\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node"
> "--module_name=bcrypt_lib"
> "--module_path=C:\user\project\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3"
> "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3"
> "--node_napi_label=napi-v3" npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd
> C:\user\project\node_modules\bcrypt npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.3
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.3.0 npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok npm ERR!
> node-pre-gyp ERR! build error npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error:
> Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
> C:\Users\Isaac\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
> configure --fallback-to-build
> --module=C:\user\project\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node
> --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\user\project\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1) npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.
> (C:\user\project\node_modules@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
> npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit
> (events.js:375:28) npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose
> (internal/child_process.js:1055:16) npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:288:5) npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System
> Windows_NT 10.0.18363 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node.exe"
> "C:\user\project\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp"
> "install" "--fallback-to-build" npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
> C:\user\project\node_modules\bcrypt npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v
> v14.17.3 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.6 npm ERR!
> node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

Comment: Update your node version first.

Comment: i did, still not working....